# IIS Express executes another console app ok but deploy to IIS doesn't run successfully

Tags: iis

I have ASP.NET application and some point I have to execute console application. Development env with IIS Express, executing console app is fine.

But I host web app in IIS and executing console app is not working and not error.

I have tried some suggestions that I found stackoverflow or other places. Still not luck.

Could someone help my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. It was because of permission. After IIS AppPool\PoolName is granted to execute assess to folder, then working fine.